# How to Protect Against Unicode Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: security, unicode, unique, string-comparison, owasp

["Five things everyone should know about Unicode"](https://gojko.net/2017/11/07/five-things-about-unicode.html) is a blog post showing how Unicode characters can be used as an attack vector for websites.

The main example given of such a real world attack is a fake WhatsApp app submitted to the Google Play store using a unicode non-printable space in the developer name which made the name unique and allowed it to get past Google's filters. The Mongolian Vowel Separator (U+180E) is one such non-printable space character.

[image]

Another vulnerability is to use alternative Unicode characters that look similar. The [Mimic](https://github.com/reinderien/mimic) tool shows how this can work.

An example I can think of is to protect usernames when registering a new user. You don't want two usernames to be the same or for them to **look** the same either.

How do you protect against this? Is there a list of these characters out there? Should it be common practice to strip all of these types of characters from all form inputs?

Comment: How *inclusive* do you want to be? If you restrict your valid input to ASCII characters there's little issue with this. The more you want to allow, the trickier it becomes.

Comment: Yes, ASCII is the simplest option but what if your usernames are multi-lingual? I'm trying to look into what Twitter does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is called a homoglyph attack.

There is a "confusables" list by Unicode [here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/revision-06/confusables.txt), and also have a look at [this](http://homoglyphs.net/). There should be libraries based on these or pontentially other databases. One such library is [this one](https://github.com/codebox/homoglyph) that you can use in Java or Javascript. The same must exist for other languages as well, or you can write one.

The important thing I think is to not have your own database - the library or service is easy to do on top of good data.

As for whether you should filter out similar looking usernames - I think it depends. If there is an interest for users to try and fake each other's usernames, maybe yes. For many other types of data, maybe there is no point in doing so. There is no generic best practice I think other than you should assess the risk in your application, with your datapoints.

Also a different approach for a different problem, but what may often work for Unicode input validation is the `\w` word character in a regular expression, if your regex engine is Unicode-ready. In such an engine, `\w` should match all Unicode classes of word characters, ie. letters, modifiers and connectors in any language, but nothing else (no special characters). This does not protect against homoglyph attacks, but may protect against some injections while keeping your application Unicode-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

All sanitization works best when you have a whitelist of known safe values, and exclude all others.

ASCII is one such set of characters.

Comment: ASCII is one example but the world is not just using English. Perhaps there needs to be a list of safe Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

This could be approached in various ways, however each one might increase the number of false positives, causing legitimate users' annoyance. Also, none of them will work for 100% of the cases (even if combined). They will just add an extra layer.

One approach would be to have tables with characters that look similar and check if duplicate names exist. What 'look similar' means is subjective in many cases, so building such list might be tricky. This method might produce false positives in certain occasions.

Also, reversing the order of certain letters might trick many users. Checking for anagrams or very similar names can be achieved using algorithms like Jaro-Winkler and Levenshtein distance (i.e., checking if a similar username/company name already exists). Sometimes however, this might be due to a different spelling of some word in some region (e.g., 'centre' vs 'center'), or the name of some company might deliberately contain an anagram. This approach might further increase the number of false positives.

Furthermore, as [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116874/jonathan) mentioned, sanitisation is also a good approach, however it might not protect against anagrams and cause issues to legitimate users who want to use some special character.

As the OP also mentioned, special characters can also be stripped. Other parts of the name might also need to be stripped, for example common names like 'Inc.', '.com' etc.

Finally, the name can be restricted to only contain characters in one language and not a mixture of characters from various languages (a more relaxed version of this may not allow mixture of characters in the same word - while would allow if separated by space). Restricting using a capital first letter and lower case for the rest of the letters can further improve this approach, as certain lower case letters (like 'l') may look like upper case ones (like 'I') when certain fonts are used. Excluding the use of certain symbols (like '|') will enhance this approach further. This solution will increase the amount of annoyance of certain users who will not be able to use certain names.

A combination of some/all aforementioned approaches can also be used. The selection of the methods and how exactly they will be applied (e.g., you may choose to forbid similar names, or to require moderator approval in case a name is similar, or to not take any action, but simply warn a moderator/administrator) depends on the scenario that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I may have an innovative solution to this problem regarding usernames. Obviously, you want to allow ASCII characters, but in some special cases, other characters will be used (different language, as you said).

I think an intuitive way to allow both ASCII and other characters to be used in an username, while being protected against "Unicode Vulnerabilities", would be something like this:

Allow all ASCII characters and disallow other characters, except when there are **x or more** of these special characters in the username(the username is in another language).

Take for example this:

**Whatsapp, Inc + (U+180E)** - Not allowed, only has 1 special character.

**элч + (U+180E)** - Allowed! It has **more than x special characters** (for example, 3). It can use the Mongolian separator since it's Mongolian.

Obviously, this does not protect you 100% from these types of vulnerabilities, but it is a very efficient method I have been using, ESPECIALLY if you do not mention the existence of this algorithm on the "login" or "register" page, as attackers might figure out that you have an algorithm protecting the website from these types of attacks, but not mention it so they cannot reverse engineer it and find a way to bypass it.

Sorry if this is not an answer you are looking for, just sharing my ideas.

Edit: Or you can use a **RNN (Recurrent Neural Network) AI** to detect the language and allow specific characters from that language.

Comment: Security by obscurity is not security.